# Unity UI Image Center Crop

Tags: android, image, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am working on listView item in Unity and stuck at fitting the image properly in UI Image. I tried multiple things using Preserver Aspect Ratop, using Filled image type almost every thing but could not make it look fine. In android we call it center crop what i am trying to achieve. First image is with Preserve Aspect while the second one is without it.
 [image: Image with Preserve Aspect but you can see you empty space at top and bottom that looks weird as compared to square images (there are some)]

[image: Image without Preserver Aspect]

What should i do to achieve it.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, can you explain or demonstrate how you want it to look like, and how it's looking like currently?

Comment: I simply want to fit it to the width and height of the UI Image and crop that goes out of it. so that no stretch appears on image.

Comment: Any chance you can predefine the width/height of the Image component? In that case we can do it with a Mask.

Comment: If you mean the UI Image, the height and width is already set thats why you see the white rectangle around image in first image (attached in question).

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it that I can think of, using 2 images. The outer image is set at your desired size and have a Mask component:

[image]

The inner image is set at center of the outer image and scaled to fit the outer image (either programatically or by hand) It will be cropped by the outer image's mask and only display the area you want.

[image]